# Apply sum before group by elaquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get the total_earning for everyday of week, like for sunday i want to get sum of all the earning of sunday, i have used the below query but this is not providing the sum:

```
$start_date = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$end_date = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$total_earning = DB::table('transactions')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('(amount-convience_fee) as total_earning'),
        DB::raw('DAYNAME(transactions.created_at) as day'),
        'currency',
        'total_time_in_mins'
    )
    ->where('tutor_id', $user_id)
    ->whereBetween('transactions.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
    ->groupBy('day')
    ->get();
```

Comment: in your select statement you need to select SUM(earnings) as earnings and then it should work

Comment: my badluck @Aless55, Thanks :)

Yes, solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this, using select raw you can sum the specific field data.

```
$total_earning = Transaction::selectRaw('sum(amount-convience_fee) as total_earning,DAYNAME(transactions.created_at) as day,created_at,tutor_id,currency,total_time_in_mins')
->where('tutor_id', $user_id)
->whereBetween('transactions.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')])
->groupBy('day')
->get();
```